# iOs8 ipad xcode 6 FBdialog doesn't rotate with the deatilview rotating

Tags: rotation, ios8, orientation, presentmodalviewcontroller, fbdialogs

In my App, it shows the `FBdialog` for sharing something on facebook timeline.

The dialog is shown by this command:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams
    clientState:nil
        handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
            } else if (results[@"completionGesture"] && [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
                NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Story published.");
            }
        }];
```

The dialog is shown on a `detailViewController`. Since ios 7 it was performing fine in ipad. but in ios8 ipad both in real device and in simulator, the fb dialog shown in always in portrait regardless of device orientation. All orientations are allowed and the `detailViewController` rotates properly but the dialog no. If I'm holding the device in landscape the dialog is 90 degree wrong, and if upside down, the dialog 180 degree.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by upgrading to latest facebook sdk framework.

Comment: I am having the same orientation issues. I am using an old FB iOS SDK 3.5.2, because my app is targeting iOS6 - iOS10. What SDK version fixed the issue for you. I want to use a version that is closest to my current version, but that will fix the problem. Thanks...